# Create a wavy pattern with pixelmator

Tags: patterns, pixelmator

How can I create a wavy pattern in pixelmator? Something like this -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a line and add multiple anchor points:

[image]

Then select alternating points while holding shift, or just one point at a time if you'd prefer. After that press arrow up or down and you will get this type of wave:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I give you one way to create waves:

Let's say you have a graphic primitive shape, i.e. line -

[image]

You select this form and open Effects Window where you choose Twirl effect and drag it to the shape:

[image]

You adjust the values in the popup window -

[image]

Click OK when you've done.  I duplicated the results just to show the waves I got -

[image]

If you want, you can apply this effect to pictures -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm stuck on applying the filter. For some reason when I click on twirl nothing happens? How do I apply the effect?

Comment: Read carefully! You should drag the filter to the shape ;)

Comment: @Illan sorry I should have specified that the dragging isn't working for the shape. I can't seem to apply it to the shape :/

Comment: @auser Convert the shape to pixels so

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there any better solution that the twirl effect, because the wave it creates isn't perfectly symmetrical?

Comment: I will add another answer, if you want, but I don't know if the pxm has this function exactly as you want it